# Cannot get importing CSV with Excel interop working properly (does not split data)

Tags: c#, csv, office-interop, excel-interop

I was looking at the solution suggested here:
[C# Excel Interop: Opening and Showing CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652621/c-sharp-excel-interop-opening-and-showing-csv-file)

```
excel.Workbooks.OpenText(filename, 
                         DataType: Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, 
                         TextQualifier: Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone,
                         ConsecutiveDelimiter: true,
                         Semicolon: true);
```

This code opens the CSV file but does not split the data on the semicolon.

If I open the file manually in Excel and use the same options as specified here it works just fine, so I must be missing something.

Any suggestions?

**Update:** Part of the CSV

```
> Betalings Enveloppe;;;;Dossier;ACME ;;;;Dagboek;;F4 - AAA
> 46846846-;;; ;;;;Rekening;54654684684684;;;;BIC;;null;;; ;;;;Betaal
> datum;Fri Mar 16 00:00:00 CET 2012;;;;EnveloppeId;;0002;;;
> Document;;Datum;Rekeningnummer;;;;BIC;Referentie;;Leverancier;;;Bedrag;
> 2012/A1/268;;29/02/2012;BE94684684684128;;;;BBRUBEBB;BLUB ;;DOKTER WHO
> ;;;28.0 ?;
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the source data you are trying to split

Comment: I've added some of part of the file. (I could just manually parse the data with c#, but I'm really interested why it doesn't work through interop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the extension is your problem.  I tried the following code with both CSV and TXT extensions, it worked as a TXT, but not as a CSV.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
public class ExcelInteropTest
{
    //private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    public static void Parse(String filename)
    {
        var _app = new Excel.Application();
        var _workbooks = _app.Workbooks;

        _workbooks.OpenText(filename,
                                 DataType: Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
                                 TextQualifier: Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone,
                                 ConsecutiveDelimiter: true,
                                 Semicolon: true);

        Excel.Sheets sheets = _workbooks[1].Worksheets;
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);

        List<String[]> excelData = new List<string[]>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "Z" + i.ToString());
            System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value;
            string[] strArray = myvalues.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
            excelData.Add(strArray);
        }

        foreach (var item in excelData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|",item));
        }

    }

}
```

All I did was create a string array for each row and add it to a list, then I just wrote each array (joined on the pipe '|', and it looks like it split everything correctly when TXT was the extension.  I would guess that the special nature CSV files have in excel might be causing the problem

Comment: Argh! I knew it (posted comment below, but I didn't see this post...)

Comment: The only problem now being that it totally does not behave like a normal spreadsheet... but that's a different question

Comment: @TimothyP Can you try opening it as a CSV, then use the TextToColumns in Excel to split it on the semicolon?  That might give you the functionality you were hoping for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you mis-copied that code but you spelled **DateType:** instead of **DataType:**.

For any delimiting to occur, the DataType has to be correct. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837097.aspx)

Another thing I often do to help past excel interop challenges is record a macro when doing something with the gui (like you said,manually opening the file in excel...) and viewing what the macro code (in VB, but should be similar) looks like.

Comment: Nvm, I didn't realize you were just putting that there for our reference. Still, give the macro a try and see if there are any subtle difference in your code...

Comment: The VBA code doesn't give me much insight either, it seems to be using the same values for the parameters...

Comment: What is the extension of the file you are importing?

Comment: It's a .csv file (exported by a closed source application)

Comment: Maybe this is stupid, but when I tried to open a .csv in excel with your sample data, it didn't convert anything. I had to remove the extension and Excel asked for the details about the delimitation. Perhaps try removing the extension and run your code again...